# Stock and Class Question

Tags: stocks, options

The current price of an American call option with exercise price is $130 written on X company is $2.40. The call option expires on March 19,2019. the current price of the stock of X company is $126.69. If you buy the stock today and the stock price rises to $140.00 before the option expires. How much $ can I expect to make by exercising the option to buy the stock and selling the stock at market value of $140.00. please include both the price of the option and the exercise price as cost.

Comment: Your description of your position  isn't clear.  If the 3/19 $130 call is written then you are short the call and you are obligated to sell the stock if the call owner exercises it.  Asking about exercising the call to buy the stock is a non starter if the call was written.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation

Comment: The current price of an American call option with exercise price $130, written on McCormick & Company stock is $2.40.  The call option expires on March 31, 2019.  The current price of one McCormick & Company stock is $126.69.  If you buy the call today and the stock price rises to $140 before your option expires, How much money would you expect to make by exercising the option to buy the stock and simultaneously selling the stock at market value of $140?  Include both the price of the option and the exercise price as costs.

Comment: perhaps i didn't word it right originally.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use the black scholes method/calculator but this question doesn't provide me with the information i need to use it

Comment: @gamma Black-Scholes isn't relevant here. OP is asking how much profit would be realized by exercising the call when the underlying reaches $140. (Even if he were asking what the price of the option would be, Black-Scholes has too many parameters to make it useful practically -- IV being the main one. Just delta * change in underlying is close enough.)

Comment: @gamma -  Black-Scholes isn't relevant here since this is an exercise question.

Comment: that sounds like a "homework" question

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework problem. Here's a hint: if you're long the call and exercise it, you get to buy the stock at the strike.

Comment: Hint #2 for the OP:  Profit equals proceeds received from sale of position less cost of "two" positions (Pssst, there are 3 transactions here). Helpful Options 201 hint for rest of the real world is sell to close options rather than exercise so that fewer  B/A slippage and commissions incurred with the exception being when ITM and bid price is below parity and  you want to avoid the haircut :->)